# how to disable firstOtherbutton of alertview

Tags: ios, ios7, uialertview

I have alert-view that has a tableview as a subview. I want to disable `firstOtherbutton` after tableview `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. I can call `alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton` but `firstotherbutton` doesn't change.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.announcement=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Announcement" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Tamam", nil];

    [announcement setValue:self.tbl.view forKey:@"accessoryView"];
    announcement.delegate =self;
    announcement.tag=100;

    [announcement show];

    [self.tbl.tableView reloadData];

}
-(void)didSelectAnswer
{
   [self performSelector:@selector(alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:) withObject:announcement afterDelay:0.001];
}

- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    if (alertView.tag==100)
    {
        if(!self.tbl.deger)
        {
            return YES;
        }
        return NO;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: that method is part of `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol and it will be invoked by the actual `UIAlertView` instance. if you call this method manually, nothing will happen.

Comment: Can you recommend anything, how can I call it?

Comment: there is no public method of the `UIAlertView` class which can serve your wish like this.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write your custom alertview to achieve this feature.

Here are some open source implementations of alertview for iOS:
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/tags/uialertview